# Tailwind CSS custom addVariant plugin is not working

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a new variant called `not-first` to the Tailwind toolbelt, but when I try to use it, it doesn't work.

**tailwind.config.js:**

```js
    const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

    module.exports = {
      mode: 'jit',
      purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx}', './public/index.html'],
      darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      variants: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [
        plugin(({ addVariant, e }) => {
          addVariant('not-first', ({ modifySelectors, separator }) => {
            modifySelectors(({ className }) => {
              const element = e(`not-first${separator}${className}`);
              return `.${element} > :not(:first-child)`;
            });
          });
        }),
      ],
    }
```

**Usage:**

```html
    <li className={`not-first:bg-blue`}>{item.name}</li>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible for you to reverse the logic and use the `first:` pseudo-class to clear the color on the first child? E.g. `<li className={"bg-blue first:bg-current"}>{item.name}</li>`

Comment: Also, if you upgrade to Tailwind V3, you'll have an easier way to add a variant: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're applying the `:not(:first-child)` to the child of the element you're targeting with the `not-first:` pseudo-class.

`:first-child` should be applied to the child element itself (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child).

To fix this, you could try changing

```js
return `.${element} > :not(:first-child)`;
```

to

```js
return `.${element}:not(:first-child)`;
```